# django devserver can't connect

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I have a situation where if I run Apache with wsgi (now uninstalled), a test website works, but running the same server with runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from local or remote (even with the apache2 service stopped).

Edit: I don't think it's Apache, I've reproduced the problem on a clean server with no Apache installed, so unless Apache somehow modified something under source control it's not that

My knowledge of web details is hazy, I don't even know where to troubleshoot this problem - the devserver runs (runserver prints as expected and doesn't give any errors) but never receives a request, I have nothing in iptables.

Comment: Why are you trying to run both servers at once?

Comment: Not trying to run both at once, I have Apache installed and eventually want to get a big app running inside it but for now would just like devserver to work again. The problem exists even when the Apache2 service is stopped

Comment: From same machine as runserver is run, can you use ``telnet localhost 8080`` to connect, or is even that refused?

Comment: telnet is also refused

Comment: Does `sudo netstat -anp | grep 8080` indicate anything is listening  on 8080 and if so is python the process hosting it?

Comment: according to that, nothing is listening on that port

note: also I've now uninstalled Apache and still can't get the devserver running

Comment: Have you checked the firewall on the server?

Comment: Yeah by running iotables, it's empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for anyone who read this, it would probably have been impossible to solve given my supplied information.

What had actually happened was that I'd been having to modify my wsgi.py script in order to make it happy inside the Apache server, and I'd added a line which said "os.system('/bin/bash --rcfile )" to try and make sure that when running inside apache it got the virtualenv activated.

This line must have been causing some strange problem, another symptom was that I realised when I was running "runserver", it wasn't crashing the the python process was backgrounding itself, where normally it runs inside that console window.

Thanks everyone who asked questions helping me debug!